# How does a prepending plus sign treat new Date?

Tags: javascript, operators

I've recently come across this intriguing line of code:

```js
var date = +new Date;

console.log(date);
```

So I experimented with putting `+` before strings to better understand what was going on and this was the result:

```js
var one = +"1"; // -> 1
var negativeTwo = -"2"; // -> -2
var notReallyANumber = +"number: 1"; // -> NaN

console.log(one, negativeTwo, notReallyANumber);
```

It seems that whenever a `+` sign or a `-` sign is placed before a string, it converts that string into a number, and if a negative sign is placed before a string, the resulting number will be negative.

Finally, if the string is not numeric, the result will be `NaN`.

Why is that?

How does putting `+` or `-` signs before a string convert it into a number and how does it also apply to `new Date`?

**EDIT:**

> How does a `+` sign affect `new Date`? How does the value `Wed Nov 07 2018 21:50:30 GMT-0500` for example, convert into a numerical representation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

Comment: @CertainPerformance the question has been edited and is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: In JavaScript, each `Object` has a `valueOf()` method. Putting `+` in front of an Object calls that method on it, and `Date` overrides it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf (also, `+new Date` is a syntax error, but JS is lenient and turns that into `+new Date()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` converts the following expression into a number, if it can. If the following expression is an *object*, then that object's `valueOf` function is called, so as to [returns the primitive value of the specified object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), which can then be (attempted) to be coerced to a number.

> How does a + sign affect new Date? How does the value Wed Nov 07 2018 21:50:30 GMT-0500 for example, convert into a numerical representation?

`Date.prototype.valueOf` returns the *integer* timestamp of the date object in question:

```js
console.log(
  new Date().valueOf()
);
```

And this method is indeed called when `+` is before a `Date` object, as you can see here (just for demonstration, this shouldn't be in real code):

```js
Date.prototype.valueOf = () => 5;
console.log(+new Date());
```

So, the `Date` object is converted to a number via `valueOf`. (This is *before* the `+` coerce-to-number operation has actually occurred, but since it's already a number, it doesn't affect anything further)